# Hrez.exe Where do I find it?

Tags: windows, resources

I have a Dmake file that uses:

REZCOMPILE      = C:/hrez/hrez.exe

I have googled and I cannot find HREZ anyplace.

Where does one get it?

-Jason

Answer (score 1):

Where did you obtain the Dmake file, from what project? Check with the authors about obtaining it. Without any context of what it is you are trying to do it is difficult to help.

Comment: I got it from here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SHAY/dmake-4.11-20080107-SHAY/
I did not create this dmake MakeFile, someone else did. I dont know where hrez.exe comes from.